# WebSockets Servers

Tags: node.js, websocket

If I have found tutorials about WebSockets, they have only been how to create Client-Side sockets. How can I create WebSocket servers and where can I get information about this (something like in Node.js)?

I don't need done Libraries for WebSockets, I need learn how to create WebSockets Servers without Libraries for WebSockets.

Thanks for replies anyone!

Comment: View the source for https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#ws-ajax

Answer (score 2):

For example [this](http://laktek.com/2010/05/04/implementing-web-socket-servers-with-node-js/) "tutorial" shows a low level WebSocket server, however it would be maybe better to look at source codes of other popular servers like [node-websocket-server](https://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server) or specific part of [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io) which deals with the WebSocket transport.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use an already-made WebSocket server. Like https://socketsbay.com/